# Setting up Angular 2 with ASP.NET Core Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I'm confronting an issue while setting up Angular 2 with an ASP.NET Core application. The application works perfectly with `dotnet` CLI but does not work with Visual Studio 2015 Update 3. Whenever I try to build the application, it shows almost 100 errors as can be seen with the screenshot below:

[image]

My `tsconfig.json` file is:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
   "target": "es5",
   "experimentalDecorators": true,
   "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
   }
 }
```

and `package.json` is:

```
{
  {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "name": "asp.net",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.4.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.9",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.26.0",
    "tsc": "1.20150623.0",
    "ts-loader": "2.0.0",
    "typescript": "2.1.5",
    "typings": "2.1.0",
    "webpack": "1.14.0"
   }
 }
```

Comment: what version of typescript do you have installed in visual studio

Comment: I ran `tsc -v` at the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0`, it says `Version 2.1.4`!

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I updated my TS for VS 2015 to 2.1.5. :)

Comment: If you found a solution to fix your problem, please post an answer with it.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I done it! Actually the problem was Typescript for Visual Studio. I installed the [latest](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593) Typescript for Visual Studio 2015 and everything was up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting below line in tsconfig.json to avoid building node_modules files

```
 "exclude": [
    "wwwroot/node_modules",
    "node_modules"
  ],
```